# A clarification about Fubini's theorem 2

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration

Suppose $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are measurable functions defined on a bounded open set $G\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($m,n\geq1$), and $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $F\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are two compact sets such that $E\times F\subset G$. Suppose
$$0\leq \int_{E} \int_{F} f(x,y)dydx\leq \int_{E} \int_{F} g(x,y)dydx  $$
and $g$ is locally integrable (so we may apply Fubini's theorem to $g$). Can we apply also Fubini to $f$ and switch the order of the above integrals of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: I believe you're thinking of non-negative functions $f$ and $g$. Otherwise, it wouldn't be difficult to find an example in which this order of integration for $f$ gives $0$ as an answer but a positive value for the inverse order... and an apropriate characteristic function as $g$ would complete the counterexample.